# Changing the logon name in Active Directory 2003

Tags: active-directory

I created a user in active directory 2003 , with the name mikedan as logon name later i went to the user properties and changed the logon name(for example to mikedannew) ,but when i go to the pc within the domain and try to access using the new login name (mikedannew) this is not working ! and when using the full upn name like mikedannew@domain.local this is working , also when using the sam name (domain\mikedan) which was not changed in my case ,  this is working too ,but typing the new logon name only not working !  .

So how can i change the user logon name only ?!

Comment: Make sure that you changed both the UPN (User Logon Name) and sAMAccoutName (User Logon Name - pre Windows 2000). If you've done that, it should definitely allow you to login (unless the system is not able to connect to AD Servers)!

Comment: Am_I_Helpful , thanks a lot it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Just as Am_I_Helful said, you just changed the logon name, so you could use the new UPN(mikedannew@domain.local) to log in. And the User Logon Name(pre Windows 2000) is still the previous (domain\mikedan) not the new (domain\mikedannew). If you want to log in with the new name(user@domain.com or domain\user), you need to change both of them.

[image]

Comment: SunnySun ,thank you my friend this worked for me , all regards